# Is there a way to use Chef as configuration server for application nodes

Tags: configuration, chef-infra, apache-zookeeper

I am currently considering using Chef for continuous deployment.
I am not too good familiar with the tool though.

I wonder, if I need additional Zookeeper server to keep track of running nodes, or I can access information from Chef in my java application directly? (From my understanding Chef already contains information for all my running nodes, so why not reuse it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, and here's the documentation: http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html

It's a slightly unusual HTTP API, that makes much heavier use of HTTP Headers than most.